# How to use evaluate

Tags: xml, saxon, xslt-3.0

I'm currently looking at our XML code for which we have a style sheet to process.

My code looks the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-model href="register_tool/rules/rules.sch" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>

<addrmap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="register_tool/rules/man_schema.xsd" name="di_do_1430_board" offset="0x0" lsb_size="32">

    <enum name="ch_handler_ch_type" bitfield="false">
        <element name="be" value="0" offset="0x00000000"/> 
    </enum>

    <addrmap name="be_sys" offset="0x00000000" offset_xpath="addrmap/enum/element[@name='be']/@offset" lsb_size="24">
        <ref name="be_reg_acc" path="blocks/be_reg_acc.xml" ref_name="be_reg_acc" offset="0x0" />
    </addrmap>

</addrmap>
```

part of my style sheet looks the following

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@offset_xpath">
    <xsl:variable name="resolved_offset"><xsl:evaluate xpath="@offset_xpath"></xsl:evaluate></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="map">
      <xsl:with-param name="offset" select="rdt:all2dec($resolved_offset)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="map">
      <xsl:with-param name="offset" select="rdt:all2dec(@offset)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:otherwise> 
</xsl:choose>
```

I am trying to get the value from my enum(ch_handler_ch_type) but using the above expression xsl:evaluate only gives me #document/fragment I cannot figure out how to get the specific value

I am using Saxon-EE 9.8.0.8

regards

**EDIT**

I have replace the xi:include with the **enum** to make it a bit clear on how the file looks. I am targeting the child **addrmap** node where the **offset_xpath** is located there i need to change the offset value. with the offset value defined in the **enum** node.

I've succeded in getting the value from the enum by using

```
<xsl:variable name="resolved_offset"><xsl:value-of><xsl:evaluate xpath="@offset_xpath" context-item="." as="xs:string"></xsl:evaluate></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
```

Now i just cant figure out how to change the attribute value offset in the node addrmap.

I've tried to make a tamplate

```
<xsl:template match="@offset[parent::addrmap]">
  <xsl:param name="resolved_offset" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="offset">
    <xsl:value-of select="$resolved_offset"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I can also see that it gets called correctly however the change does not happen

Comment: Please show us the context (literally), we cannot decide whether the `xsl:choose` or the `xsl:evaluate` makes any sense without knowing the context node (defined by e.g. `xsl:template match` or `xsl:for-each select`) the outer code has set up.

Comment: Check that the `xi:include` is actually being expanded: this depends on setting the right options (-xi) and on using the right XML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is necessary to define the `context-item` for `xsl:evaluate`, if we assume you have the `xsl:evaluate` in the context of the inner `addrmap` then the path you have `addrmap/enum/element[@name='be']/@offset` only makes sense if you want to evaluate it relative to the root node `/` so you would need e.g.

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="@offset_xpath" context-item="/" as="xs:string"/>
```

or you need to change the path. I have added the `as="xs:string"` as selecting a single attribute node and not its value can lead to problems with your `xsl:value-of`.

Here is a more complete example of `xsl:evaluate`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="enum"/>

    <xsl:template match="addrmap[@offset_xpath]/ref/@offset">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:evaluate xpath="../../@offset_xpath" context-item="/"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms your latest input sample into

```
<addrmap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="di_do_1430_board" offset="0x0" lsb_size="32">



    <addrmap name="be_sys" offset="0x00000000" offset_xpath="addrmap/enum/element[@name='be']/@offset" lsb_size="24">
        <ref name="be_reg_acc" path="blocks/be_reg_acc.xml" ref_name="be_reg_acc" offset="0x00000000"/>
    </addrmap>

</addrmap>
```

so as you can see the attribute `offset` of the `ref` child of the `addrmap` element has been changed.

Still can't make sense of your attempt with the given path and `context-item="."` because I don't see why then the relative path `addrmap/enum/element[@name='be']/@offset` would select anything.

In the previous sample it is not clear what `rdt:all2dec` does or is needed for, in general I think attempts to use `xsl:choose/xsl:when` to check for a certain node structure are easier handled by simply writing match patterns like I have done with `match="addrmap[@offset_xpath]/ref/@offset`, for the other case you can then use e.g. `<xsl:template match="addrmap[not(@offset_xpath)]/ref/@offset">`.

Comment: rdt:all2dec is an internal function that converts all value types strings into a decimal number

Comment: When I use your above code, It does everything correctly except when setting the attribute. there i get **Cannot create an attribute node (offset) whose parent is a document node. Most recent element start tag was output at line -1 of module *unknown***

Comment: I don't see how you can get that error given that the complete stylesheet has `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` which takes care of copying all nodes and then simply has a template to handle the attribute and recreate it with a different value. So in my test that does work and can't produce that error.

Comment: I have it working now. not sure what was wrong maybe a type error